# replacing marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem on replacing a marker on google maps.
I know questions have already been answered about markers on google maps but here it seems I have a problem I didn't see any solution for.
The icon appears but the marker appears as well, how can I remove it and only keep the icon?
Thanks for your help

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-14.320180, -47.267077),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

var image = 'flag.png'
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.906847,-43.172896);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    optimized: false,
    title: 'Rio de Janeiro'

});
```

`

Comment: It mean remove (x) from bottom of marker ??

Comment: i would like to remove the google basic red marker by an icon

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The code you have posted only contains one marker and doesn't remove it.

Comment: i followed the code provided by Google "Customize a marker image" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers but in my case the initial red marker remains

Answer (score 1):

you can create 1 value of type (restaurants,hotels) or set default value of validate, Url is image you want to set your marker;

and try this code:

```
var url ="http://exampl.com/yellow.png";   
marker = google.maps.Marker({
       icon: url;
       position: place.geometry.location,
       map: map
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your icon to be displayed and not the marker, just place an icon (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) on your map and not a marker.